# Scrapy: Downloading base64 image in another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, multiprocessing

I have a Spider like the following, which get information from an API, besides of this, I want to download product images in base64 format, but the crawling process becomes so slow, how can I do it in another way, for example, using threads?

```
class ExampleMobilePhoneSpider(Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com", "example.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://search.example.com/api/search/?category=c11&pageno=0',
    )
custom_settings = {
    "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
        'crawler_bot.pipelines.ExampleElectronicDevicePipeline': 100,
    }
}

def parse_item(self, response):
    js = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
    hits = js['hits']['hits']
    for counter, hit in enumerate(hits):
        l = ItemLoader(item=ProductDetail(), response=response)
        m = hits[counter]['_source']

        # print(json.dumps(m, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        l.add_value('enTitle', m['EnTitle'])
        l.add_value('faTitle', m['FaTitle'])
        l.add_value('minPrice', {"value": m['MinPrice'], "updateDate": datetime.datetime.now()})
        l.add_value('price', {"value": m['MinPriceList'], "updateDate": datetime.datetime.now()})
        l.add_value('maxPrice', {"value": m['MaxPrice'], "updateDate": datetime.datetime.now()})
        l.add_value('isActive', m['IsActive'])
        l.add_value('isEspecialOffer', m['IsSpecialOffer'])
        l.add_value('productCategories', m['ProductCategories'].split())
        l.add_value('imagePath', m['ImagePath'])
        l.add_value('hasVideo', m['HasVideo'])
        l.add_value('productColorList', m['ProductColorList'])
        l.add_value('localID', m['Id'])

        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('project', "example")
        l.add_value('subject', ["electronic_device", "mobile_phone", "mobile"])
        l.add_value('spider', self.name)
        l.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        l.add_value('collection', "electronic_device")

        file_path = "https://file.example.com/example/"
        l.add_value('images', image2base64.get_as_base64(file_path + m['ImagePath']))

        yield l.load_item()

def parse(self, response):
    base_url_mobile = 'https://search.example.com/api/search/?category=c11&pageno='
    urls = [base_url_mobile + str(n) for n in range(2)]
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_item)
```

Comment: did you try it by implementing a downloader pipeline?

Comment: With pipeline I just store data in MongoDB and Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Mixing your own threads with scrapy is usually a bad idea. Also it is not necessary, Scrapy is using Twisted's implementation of the Reactor Pattern for concurrency and can handle 1000s of requests simultaneously if the hardware is sufficiently sized ... and the settings in settings.py allow it.

As I can't see your image pipeline implmentation and also not your settings.py this is a bit a guess, but you should try these two things:

1. increase the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS setting, otherwise your spider will download only a limited number of pages and files at the same time
2. Check your image pipeline for any cpu-intensive processing or blocking behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways, below example with a queue and a bunch of worker threads to do request/response processing and image downloading.

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue


class ExampleMobilePhoneSpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, num_workers=10, q_size=100):
        self.in_q = Queue(q_size)
        self.worker_threads = [Thread(
                                  target=self.worker, args=(self.in_q,))
                              for _ in range(num_workers)]
        for _thread in self.worker_threads:
            _thread.daemon = True
            _thread.start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            _url = self.in_q.get()
            Request(_url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse(self, response):
        base_url_mobile = 'https://search.example.com/api/search/?category=c11&pageno='
        urls = [base_url_mobile + str(n) for n in range(2)]
        for url in urls:
            self.in_q.add(urljoin(response.url, url))
```

Comment: Did you test your code? Besides mixing threads with scrapy which isn't a good idea, your code looks like it will spin up some threads to create a lot of scrapy Request objects that will never be executed ...

Comment: The OP code example is not complete and has bad indentation so no, it is not possible to test any code based on it. Did you have any specific questions? What have you tried so far? There's lots of ways to do this, can easily make the thread target function be the image downloading and not do any parsing/scrapy use in them at all. It depends what you want. Either way, you will need to show some working code and ask questions based on that.